# Message sends object but makes object properties null

Tags: android, multithreading, messaging

I have multi-threaded application sends messages between threads. I send a message with this method

```
public static void sendToListener(SomeObject someobject, Object obj) {

    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.setTarget(ResponseClass.responseMessageHandler);
    Vector<Object> v = new Vector<Object>();
    v.add(someobject);
    v.add(obj);
    msg.obj = v;
    msg.arg1 = someobject.id;
        Log.d(TAG,someobject.str); // property named str is not null
    msg.sendToTarget();
}
```

and i receive with;

```
public static Handler responseMessageHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Vector<Object> v = (Vector<Object>) msg.obj;
        SomeObject so = (SomeObject) v.elementAt(0);
        Object o = v.elementAt(1);
        Log.d(TAG,so.str); // property named str is null
    }
};
```

If i send message with an object, object is sent with no problem, but String properties of object are sent as null. All primitive typed properties are correct such as booleans and integers.

Comment: What release are you using. From te docs - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html#obj

Comment: i am using sdk version 4 (android1.6)

Comment: Why don't you use the standart way via Bundle. Bundle data = new Bundle(); data.putSerializable(v);msg.setData(data);

Comment: @Mojo Risin, thanks. i see the problem. But i do not want to use `setData(Bundle bundle)` method. It is slow when i send serializable object.

Comment: Are all these threads running in the same process? If you've declared them to run in different processes in your manifest, then complex types aren't going to survive the process boundary traversal. Also, you should never be calling `new Message()`, always use Message.obtain() or Handler.obtainMessage().